# Opening Multiple excel files automation

Tags: excel, vbscript, python-requests, vba

I have thousands of macro enabled excel files. I have to open each one and generate an output file (clicking one button).

Can someone help me to automate this, please?

Comment: Have the macros in all them files got the same name?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code writing service.  You should consider hiring someone to do this for you if you're completely unclear on how to take on what seems to be a very large task.

Comment: @ Xabier, yes all the files has the same Macro. It is a button

Comment: @ Graham, Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Have an centralised macro sheet which has two columns one should contains all macro workbookname and another column with function Name to control all macros .
pass input as SheetName and Macro name
Example:

Application.Run ("'Analytics macro S17.xlsm'!getdata")

Just Iterate the above lines to take different macro sheet name with operations.

Comment: Thank you Vadivelu, I will try